# Impala SQL in Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: sql, jupyter-notebook, impala

Can anybody help me with the correct syntax to run multi line Impala - SQL queries in Jupyter notebooks. I have been using the approach below to run queries on a single line but have not been able to work out how to run multi line queries with indentation.

```
! impala-shell -q 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT eyesight_evaluation.patient_id FROM eyesight_evaluation WHERE severity_of_sight_loss IN ("Slight","Mild","Moderate","Moderately Severe","Severe","Profound")) AS TotalDiagnosed;'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 3 single quotes for multi-line comments

```
'''SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT eyesight_evaluation.patient_id FROM
   eyesight_evaluation WHERE severity_of_sight_loss IN 
   ("Slight","Mild","Moderate","Moderately Severe","Severe","Profound")) AS TotalDiagnosed;'''
```